# How to scroll widget in same time with grid Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, scaffold

**How I can scroll widget in same time**

Flutter

**Screenshot**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tomR.jpg)

**Here is code for this screen**

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: CustomAppBar(
      scaffoldKey: widget.scaffoldKey,
      // icon: AppIcon.settings,
      // onActionPressed: onSettingIconPressed,
      onSearchChanged: (text) {
        setState(() {
          if (text.length > 0) {
            searching = true;
          } else {
            searching = false;
          }
        });

        state.filterByUsername(text);
      },
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: new RefreshIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        onRefresh: () async {
          HapticFeedback.selectionClick();
          setState(() {
            list3 = state2.getPostList(authstate.userModel);
            list3.shuffle();
            onlyImages.shuffle();
          });
          state.getDataFromDatabase();
          return Future.value(true);
        },

        // mesto povise greed, i ispod search boxa

        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            searching
                ? ListView.separated(
                    addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        _UserTile(user: list[index]),
                    separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: list?.length ?? 0,
                  )
                : slider(),
            searching
                ? ListView.separated(
                    addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        _UserTile(user: list[index]),
                    separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: list?.length ?? 0,
                  )
                : Container(
                    height: 32,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _tagItem(Icon(Icons.dehaze, color: Colors.orange),
                              'DAJGI', null, Colors.black, () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context, '/PhoneConfirmCode');
                          }),
                          _tagItem(null, 'Nature', null,
                              Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.3), null),
                          _tagItem(
                              null, 'Animal', null, Colors.brown, null),
                          _tagItem(null, 'Travel', null, Colors.teal, null),
                          _tagItem(
                              null, 'Happy', null, Colors.orange, null),
                          _tagItem(null, 'Art', null, Colors.blue, null),
                          _tagItem(
                              null, 'Night', null, Colors.blueGrey, null),
                        ]),
                  ),

            // Grid List
            _listOfPosts(),

            // Expanded(
            //   child: GridView.count(
            //     crossAxisCount: 3,
            //     children: List.generate(onlyImages.length, (index) {
            //       return GestureDetector(
            //           onTap: () {
            //             FeedModel model = onlyImages[index];
            //             onPostPressed(context, model);
            //           },
            //           // onLongPress: () {
            //           //   _createPopupContext;
            //           //   FeedModel model = onlyImages[index];
            //           //   onPostPressed(context, model);
            //           // },
            //           child: Container(
            //             child: Card(
            //                 child: onlyImages
            //                             .elementAt(index)
            //                             .imagesPath
            //                             .length >
            //                         0
            //                     ? CachedNetworkImage(
            //                         imageUrl: onlyImages
            //                             .elementAt(index)
            //                             .imagesPath[0],
            //                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
            //                       )
            //                     :
            //                     // Container()
            //                     Center(
            //                         child: Text(onlyImages
            //                             .elementAt(index)
            //                             .description),
            //                       )),
            //           ));
            //     }
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        )));
```

When I starting to scroll now only grid scrolling but widget not moving, and I want that this widget going up when user starting to scroll.. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Updated the full code as requested in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Column` is un-scrollable, so to make widgets scrollable is to wrap those widgets with a `ListView` instead of a `Column`. So you can do something like this to make widgets scrollable:

```
RefreshIndicator(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    onRefresh: (_){},
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        // widget 1,
        // widget 2,
        // widget 3,
      ],
),
```

If `ListView` make widgets scrollable, what happens when a `ListView` is wrap in another `ListView`? A scrollable inside a scrollable? (Well there are some cases when you want to do this, but thats not the case here so yeah). There will be error.

So to avoid the error, just add `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` and you're good to go, as such:

```
RefreshIndicator(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  onRefresh: (_){},
  child: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      // listview
      ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,                 // <--- add this
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // <--- and this
        ...
      ),
      // gridview
      GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,                 // <--- add this
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // <--- and this
        ...
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```